# C++ long int casting confusion

Tags: c++, casting

Ok guys I am fairly new to C++ and I am kind of confused on what is happening here so I am not even sure if my title is an accurate description of my problem but here goes nothing.

SO, I have a header file that has two long variables in it.

```
long num, denom;
```

Then, in my .cc file I have a constructor that takes two longs to set these variables and two ints to set these variables. The int constructor is below.

```
Ratio::Ratio(int numerator, int denominator){
num =  long(numerator);
denom =  long(denominator);
this->normalize();}
```

I am assuming I have to cast my parameters to longs in order to store them in the long variables that I declared in my header file.

When trying to compile I am getting an error: ` error: no
   declaration matches ‘long int Ratio::numerator()’
   30 | long Ratio::numerator(){return num;}

My current numerator function is just a simple getter

```
long Ratio::numerator(){return num;}
```

My guess is that when I cast these to long in the constructor, it is creating a long int. Then, the compiler is looking for a numerator function that takes long int parameters instead of long (like the one I already have made) but doesn't find it. Any idea how to fix this without creating a numerator function that takes a long int? I have to have the constructor that takes ints and be able to store them into my long variables num and denom. Any help is appreciated! Thanks
`

Comment: As written the question is as much confuse as you are. Provided code is not sufficient to understand what you are doing wrong. For ex. your error message is related to a `numerator` function that we don't see.

Comment: Just edited to include the numerator function. It is just a simple getter and is declared in my header file.

Comment: Please provide a [repro] for your problem. Nothing that you have shown or described generates the error message you are mentioning. It is not related to the constructor or any casting at all. The explicit casts to `long` in the constructor are redundant, they are already done implicitly. Why are you taking two `int` to store as `long`? `int` may have smaller range of values, so why not take `long` parameters directly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those values should be able to convert implicitly, because int is smaller than long so it is always well defined.  You should provide the contents of the header file, because mistakes where variables are declared are typically the source of these compiler warnings.

Comment: I found the problem it was in the header file, thanks! I wanted to use int numerator(long numerator) const; When declaring my function but when I remove the const it works. ANy idea why?

Comment: "*because int is smaller than long so it is always well defined.*": Implicit conversion happens whether or not the conversion is narrowing, because OP is not using brace initialization.

Comment: @MichaelFoster Then please provide a proper [repro] for this error in your question.